# Swift Alamofire - fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value - youtube api: PlaylistItems: list

Tags: swift, youtube-api, fatal-error, alamofire

This is my code: breaking point is at. videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl =

I placed a breaking point at. arrayOfVideos.append(videoObj). on the bottom tab where (lldb) is placed. I entered: "po videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl" while having a breaking point at .append.
it returned with the url. but when i placed the breaking point on videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl. and entered: "po videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl" it returned with empty quotes ""
i am trying to receive data from youtubev3api-playlist using the snippet method. Extracting the data with the value for key method.

I removed the url from the. "snippet.thumbnails.maxres" and try run it but i got this error: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFDictionary' (0x105c4eef0) to 'NSString' (0x10603fb20).

```
for video in JSON["items"] as! NSArray {

 let videoObj = Video()

 videoObj.videoId = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.resourceId.videoId") as! String

 videoObj.videoTitle = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.title") as! String

 videoObj.videoDescription = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.description") as! String

 videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url") as! String

                arrayOfVideos.append(videoObj)
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use forced casts or forced unwraps as these cause your application to crash if they encounter nil values. Just like in your case. Instead use [optional bindings](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID333) and [optional chaining](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html) to detect and handle `nil` values.

```
if let items = JSON["items"] as? NSArray {
    for video in items {
        let videoObj = Video()            
        videoObj.videoId = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.resourceId.videoId") as? String            
        videoObj.videoTitle = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.title") as? String            
        videoObj.videoDescription = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.description") as? String            
        videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url") as? String            
        arrayOfVideos.append(videoObj)
    }
}
```

Please note that this code no longer uses forced casts, so in the eventuality of the `Youtube API` not sending some of the fields, then we'll simply have `nil` values for those, instead of crashing.

And also we [conditionally cast](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID341) to `NSArray` and combined with the conditional binding, we only loop against the items if they're actually an array.

Comment: I replaced the "!" with "?" and got a different error. value of optional type string not unwrapped:...

Comment: it was a amateur mistake. I replaced maxres with default/medium/high and it ran okay. no errors. :)  This is my first project excuse me for the mistake. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

If you place a breakpoint onto a source code and the thread is paused on your breakpoint, it means the breakpointed line is not executed yet.

When your thread is paused on the

> videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl = video.valueForKeyPath("snippet.thumbnails.maxres.url") as! String

then press `step over`. This moves your thread 1 line below.

And you should be able to see the assigned value of the `videoObj.videoThumbnailUrl`

Comment: okay i thought that might of been a sign to the issue. still getting the error. fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. when i run project